# How to dismiss a particular dialog using its id

Tags: android

I found `removeDialog(id)` and `dismissDialog(id)` is deprecated. How to dismiss a dialog using its id. Different type of dialogs are associated with different id in my application. in some case i have to show progressdialog, and in some other case alert dialog also i am showing different messages. thats why I am passing id to showDialog(id) method to show dialog. Now I want to dismiss a particular dialog. I have the id of the dialog. How to dismiss the dialog.

Thaanks
Sunil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably read it at [javadoc for Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). You may also notice that [showDialog()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) is deprecated as well. It is suggested to use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead, but since it was only introduced in API 11, and if your app is targeted for lower APIs, I believe its totally okay to continue using showDialog() and removeDialog().

Answer (score 0):

`dismissDialog(id)`

You should have a look here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog

Answer (score 0):

Look at the javadoc on the developer site for [`dismissDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dismissDialog%28int%29). It says

> This method is deprecated.
>
> Use the new DialogFragment class with FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

so you could look into using [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and [`FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html), as they are the suggested replacement.

Comment: DialogFragment is not present for api level 7 My application has to support from SDK version 3 and onwards

Comment: In that case I think it is safe to use `dismissDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `showDialog()` and `dismissDialog()` is deprecated in SDK API level 11, you could use support package to use `DialogFragment` to have backward compatibility.

[Support Package Link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)